# Is there an adjective describing a filter with kernel that has zero mean?

Tags: filters, bandpass, highpass-filter, terminology, kernel

A linear filter with a kernel that has zero mean could be thought of as a "DC-rejecting" filter. Is there a better or more commonly used adjective for such a filter?

Comment: Highpass, bandpass?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen one word that includes both of those

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Zero-Mean" is the word that's commonly used to describe signals and signals with a zero average. "This is a zero-mean filter."

If you really mean a filter that is specifically meant to cancel the DC component, a "DC blocker" is a name for that.

Answer (score 3):

In complement to Marcus, I have read the term "zero-sum": "zero-sum window", "zero-sum filter", "zero-sum kernel", the latter being more frequent. It is similar to "unit-sum windows", ie windows whose amplitudes sum to one. "Zero-average" can be found in image processing:

> Further note that applying any alternative zero-average filter (in
> [Fragmentation in the Vision of Scenes](https://doi.org/10.1109/ICCV.2003.1238326)).

I however have met the term more on the opposite side: "non zero-sum" to characterize a window choose coefficients don't add to zero, which could be turned into a unit-sum window.

Answer (score 1):

In audio applications, this would be a *low-cut filter*. The term is often used synonymous with *high pass*, though that would not accurately describe general zero-mean filters.

A unit-mean filter meanwhile is indeed a lowpass filter.